# Looping Caeser Cipher characters with both upper and lowercase letters

Tags: python

How can I make the caeser cipher go through the ASCII characters with both the upper and lowercase letters. I have the code working fine if i just do uppercase letters. Here's my closest attempt at having both upper and lower case letters, however if you do for instance, Z and have a key = 1, it will still give me the [ character. so From the ASCII table, I have to exclude characters 91-96 and any other characters which aren't upper or lowercase alphabet letters.

Comment: What do you want to do with chars in `userPhrase` that aren't letters? Do you just want to copy them to `finalmsg`?

Comment: Not sure I exactly get what you're asking. But if it helps, this is missing a lot of my code as I created a GUI platform for this, where userPhrase and key and so on are all defined later in the code by user inputs.

I'm basically just trying to make it so in my encoding part, if the user types xyzXYZ and a key of 3, it should read abcABC and not {l}[\]

Comment: @Jim: He's asking what `encode('!@1234', 1)` should do.

Comment: @ Joshua, technically nothing because i don't want the possiblity of numbers and other characters, I edited my last comment to explain what i would like my outcome to look like if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is probably a homework assignment, here's some pseudo-code.

1. If the character is lower-case, set `ord('a')` as `base`. Else-if the character is upper-case, set `ord('A')` as `base`. Else `return char`.
2. Add `ord(char) - base` and `key` modulo 26.
3. Add `base` back to the result.

This procedure can be optimized, but that's probably work you should do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to just use the modulus operator. So all you need to do is check if the `ch.isupper()` or not and subtract the appropriate base value:

```
def encode(userPhrase, key):
    finalmsg = userPhrase
    word = ""
    for ch in finalmsg:
        base = ord('A') if ch.isupper() else ord('a')
        new_ch = (ord(ch)-base+key) % 26 + base
        word += chr(new_ch)
    return word

>>> encode("HelloWorld", 10)
RovvyGybvn
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `ord('a') > new_ch > ord('z')` and `ord('A') > new_ch > ord('Z')` are both guaranteed to be false so they don't anything.

Second, you need separate conditions to handle under and overflow.

```
def encode(userPhrase, key):
  finalmsg = userPhrase
  word = ""
  for ch in finalmsg:
    new_ch = ord(ch) + int(key)
    if ch.isupper() and new_ch > ord('Z'):
      new_ch -= 26
    elif ch.islower() and new_ch > ord('z'):
      new_ch -= 26
    elif ch.isupper() and new_ch < ord('A'):
      new_ch += 26
    elif ch.islower() and new_ch < ord('a'):
      new_ch += 26
    word += chr(new_ch)
  return word

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(encode('azAZ', 1)) # 'baBA'
  print(encode('azAZ', -1)) # 'zyZY'
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your test is backwards. You only want to do the subtraction if `new_ch` is *outside* the A-Z or a-z range. So to fix your code with minimal changes, you can do this:

```
def encode(userPhrase, key):
    word = ""
    key = int(key)
    for ch in userPhrase:
        new_ch = ord(ch) + key
        if not ((ord('A') > new_ch > ord('Z')) or (ord('a') > new_ch > ord('z'))):
            new_ch -= 26
        word += chr(new_ch)
    return word

#Test
print(encode('xyzXYZ', 3))
```

**output**

```
abcABC
```

But as the other answers mention, there are simpler ways to do this. I'd probably use something like AChampion's code.